# Using a Stack structure to reverse a String/Word

Tags: java

I'm wondering how to reverse a user inputed word or string in java
I've done the easy part ..

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Stack
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Please enter a word to reverse: ");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String name=sc.nextLine();


    }

     private int maxSize; // size of stack array
     private long[] stackArray;
     private int top; // top of stack
     public Stack(int s) { // constructor
         maxSize = s; // set array size
         stackArray = new long[maxSize]; // create array
         top = -1; // no items yet
        }    
     public void push(long j) { // put item on top of stack 
         top++;
         stackArray[top] = j; // increment top, insert item
        }
     public long pop() { // take item from top of stack

         return stackArray[top--]; //access item, decrement top
        } 
}
```

This basically just takes in the user input and does nothing (and has pop and push methods)

Just wondering if someone could help me reverse the string lets say 'hello' (keep in mind its a user submitted string however)

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Well, what happens when you push each character in a word into a stack?

Comment: You're almost there! Inserting "Hello" to a stack --> `[H, e, l, l, o ->`. Popping each element from the stack, `o` pops first, then l, l, e and finally H.

Comment: Do you need to use a stack because you could use StringBuilder.reverse...

Comment: In main method parse your incoming String and do a push of each char. Then do a pop till your stack is empty. Make sure your popped chars are appended to each other. That's all

Answer (score 2):

1. You have a stack of `long`'s but you'd like a stack of `char`s. How would you try to fix this?
2. What would happen if you pushed 2 chars onto your stack, then popped them both, appending each to a new string sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

```
//part 1: user input
    System.out.println("Enter The Word: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String Scanner = scanner.next();

//part 2: The method to reverse

    String reverse = new StringBuffer(Scanner).reverse().toString();
    System.out.println(reverse);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use the Stack collection from java, and you just push each character into it.
Then pop everyone of them and concatenate them, you will have the reversed word.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String word = "WORD";
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        stack.push(word.substring(i,i+1));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(stack.pop());
    }
    System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
}
```

Comment: @Kayaman i know how to actually reverse it...
its more how to split the string into chars to pop them etc

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a little help, if he is asking he already thought about it himself. But either way i gave you the answer with the Stack collection, you have to implement it with arrays, i just gave you half the way.

Comment: @luisdurazoa You wrote out the code for him, that's not "a little help".

Comment: @John_K Next time you should say what you need help with, it'll make things easier for everyone.

Comment: The only thing useful for him in my answer is this word.substring(i,i+1) and i dont see how my answer is to be downvoted following StackOverflow policies.